# SQL: Converting data in date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, ssms

I have many tables with date fields, such as [Due Date], [Expiration Date], etc.
The format of the date is 2014-08-06.

I have label software that reads data directly from the database. For example, it will pull a record and print out 'Use by:' [Expiration Date].

Following proper documentation standards, this expiration date, and all other date fields, should be in the following format instead:

06 Aug 2014

Is the only sound way of achieving this to create a duplicated field **for every date field** on **every table** and run a query that copies and converts the data into that new varchar field?

Comment: can you point this sw at a storedprocedure?  or a view?

Comment: What software is reading the data?  Why can't it do something as simple as format an output date?  Why can't the queries it uses to retrieve data be customized?  You could always create a `VIEW` and point it at that...  I guess the VIEW should return already formatted strings instead of dates.

Comment: The `date` hasn't any representation by itself.

Comment: A google search on "ms access date format" lead me to this.  http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php

Comment: If it was not easy to do this in the query itself I would create a view to modify the field like the suggestion by @ebyrob.

Answer (score 2):

To do this within MS Access you will want to use the Format command.

It will take the form of:

Format (MyDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

the mmm for the month will show the Month as an abbreviated string.

More here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php

Answer (score 0):

When selecting the date from SQL itself, you can convert the datetime field with a specific format by using the CONVERT function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 106)
```

The 106 is a code that translates as a long date format. So today, this gives me:

```
13 May 2014
```

To use it, just incorporate it into your select statements and perhaps provide an alias using AS:

```
SELECT
ID,
CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Due Date], 106) as 'DueDate'
FROM [myTableName]
```

Comment: @DanBracuk No idea. The question is also tagged with tsql, where it will certainly work

Answer (score 0):

The best was is, as stated above, to have **your software format the date**.

If that is not possible and write access is negotiable, you may want to **replace your use of tables with views**.

```
Create view v_SelectVisits
AS
select 
    ID
    , DateTimeIn as DateTimeIn_old
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateTimeIn, 106) as  DateTimeIn 
from visit
GO
select * from v_SelectVisits
```

If views will not work for you, you can add a **calculated column** to your tables for all your dates (*Are you SURE you cannot take option #1?*)

```
Alter Table MyTable
Add DateTimeIn_C as CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateTimeIn, 106)
```

Comment: Why add a calculated column where you can covert the select output directly, as per my example?

Comment: If he cannot change the SQL that is pulling the data, but can only "attach to a table" then he may have to resort to this.  It sounds like he has little or no control over the program consuming the data.  I like your suggestion and would absolutely do that before altering the table.  But as I know we all agree with, have the GUI format the date, if at all possible!

Comment: Fair enough. There's not enough background given to assess what's the best option. But altering the table really should be the last resort - if he can do that, I'm sure he also has permission to build a view or change the select statement.